# Google maps API can't find a callback defined in $(document).ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I have a problem with Jquery and Google Maps API.

Scripts seem to be located correctly in html

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=KEY&callback=initMap"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/stomp.js/2.3.3/stomp.min.js"></script>
```

The problem is that init map is inside $(document).ready

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    let url = "ws://localhost:61614/";
    let topic = "stomp.topic";
    let client;

    let map, trackers = {};

    $("#connect_button").click(function () {
        connect(url);
        return false;
    });

    $("#disconnect_button").click(function () {
        disconnect();
        return false;
    });

    function initMap() {
        let mapOptions = {
            zoom: 8,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(30, 0),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions)

    }
}
```

How correctly initMap must be accessed ?

Comment: The scope of `initMap` is limited to the callback function that you pass to `.ready`. You need to define Google maps' callback function as a property of `window`.

Comment: it doesn't help

Comment: Yet it is the correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

I think you forgot to call `initMap` function.

Try this - https://jsitor.com/227rClFCE,

The callback in scripts path `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=KEY&callback=initMap` will look for global method name `initMap`, however it is not defined globally and scoped inside `document.ready` scope so it won't execute. Either call the method inside `document.ready` callback or else after add this method inside `Window` object by doing `Window.initMap = initMap` below `initMap` function.