# Change mapbox on google maps

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, mapbox

I am trying swich map box to google maps in some map app.
This shows polyline on map, but i have one problem.

**Here is my code :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Simple Map</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>


    <script src="https://portal.company.io/theme/plugins/moment.js"></script>

    <script src="https://portal.company.io/Scripts/googlemap/mapstyle.js"></script>
    <script src="https://portal.company.io/Scripts/googlemap/markerclusterer.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        (function(t,e){"function"==typeof define&&define.amd?define(["leaflet"],t):"object"==typeof exports&&(module.exports=t(require("leaflet"))),e!==void 0&&e.L&&(e.LeafletLabel=t(L))})(function(t){t.labelVersion="0.2.4";var e=t.Class.extend({includes:t.Mixin.Events,options:{className:"",clickable:!1,direction:"right",noHide:!1,offset:[12,-15],opacity:1,zoomAnimation:!0},initialize:function(e,i){t.setOptions(this,e),this._source=i,this._animated=t.Browser.any3d&&this.options.zoomAnimation,this._isOpen=!1},onAdd:function(e){this._map=e,this._pane=this.options.pane?e._panes[this.options.pane]:this._source instanceof t.Marker?e._panes.markerPane:e._panes.popupPane,this._container||this._initLayout(),this._pane.appendChild(this._container),this._initInteraction(),this._update(),this.setOpacity(this.options.opacity),e.on("moveend",this._onMoveEnd,this).on("viewreset",this._onViewReset,this),this._animated&&e.on("zoomanim",this._zoomAnimation,this),t.Browser.touch&&!this.options.noHide&&(t.DomEvent.on(this._container,"click",this.close,this),e.on("click",this.close,this))},onRemove:function(t){this._pane.removeChild(this._container),t.off({zoomanim:this._zoomAnimation,moveend:this._onMoveEnd,viewreset:this._onViewReset},this),this._removeInteraction(),this._map=null},setLatLng:function(e){return this._latlng=t.latLng(e),this._map&&this._updatePosition(),this},setContent:function(t){return this._previousContent=this._content,this._content=t,this._updateContent(),this},close:function(){var e=this._map;e&&(t.Browser.touch&&!this.options.noHide&&(t.DomEvent.off(this._container,"click",this.close),e.off("click",this.close,this)),e.removeLayer(this))},updateZIndex:function(t){this._zIndex=t,this._container&&this._zIndex&&(this._container.style.zIndex=t)},setOpacity:function(e){this.options.opacity=e,this._container&&t.DomUtil.setOpacity(this._container,e)},_initLayout:function(){this._container=t.DomUtil.create("div","leaflet-label "+this.options.className+" leaflet-zoom-animated"),this.updateZIndex(this._zIndex)},_update:function(){this._map&&(this._container.style.visibility="hidden",this._updateContent(),this._updatePosition(),this._container.style.visibility="")},_updateContent:function(){this._content&&this._map&&this._prevContent!==this._content&&"string"==typeof this._content&&(this._container.innerHTML=this._content,this._prevContent=this._content,this._labelWidth=this._container.offsetWidth)},_updatePosition:function(){var t=this._map.latLngToLayerPoint(this._latlng);this._setPosition(t)},_setPosition:function(e){var i=this._map,n=this._container,o=i.latLngToContainerPoint(i.getCenter()),s=i.layerPointToContainerPoint(e),a=this.options.direction,l=this._labelWidth,h=t.point(this.options.offset);"right"===a||"auto"===a&&s.x<o.x?(t.DomUtil.addClass(n,"leaflet-label-right"),t.DomUtil.removeClass(n,"leaflet-label-left"),e=e.add(h)):(t.DomUtil.addClass(n,"leaflet-label-left"),t.DomUtil.removeClass(n,"leaflet-label-right"),e=e.add(t.point(-h.x-l,h.y))),t.DomUtil.setPosition(n,e)},_zoomAnimation:function(t){var e=this._map._latLngToNewLayerPoint(this._latlng,t.zoom,t.center).round();this._setPosition(e)},_onMoveEnd:function(){this._animated&&"auto"!==this.options.direction||this._updatePosition()},_onViewReset:function(t){t&&t.hard&&this._update()},_initInteraction:function(){if(this.options.clickable){var e=this._container,i=["dblclick","mousedown","mouseover","mouseout","contextmenu"];t.DomUtil.addClass(e,"leaflet-clickable"),t.DomEvent.on(e,"click",this._onMouseClick,this);for(var n=0;i.length>n;n++)t.DomEvent.on(e,i[n],this._fireMouseEvent,this)}},_removeInteraction:function(){if(this.options.clickable){var e=this._container,i=["dblclick","mousedown","mouseover","mouseout","contextmenu"];t.DomUtil.removeClass(e,"leaflet-clickable"),t.DomEvent.off(e,"click",this._onMouseClick,this);for(var n=0;i.length>n;n++)t.DomEvent.off(e,i[n],this._fireMouseEvent,this)}},_onMouseClick:function(e){this.hasEventListeners(e.type)&&t.DomEvent.stopPropagation(e),this.fire(e.type,{originalEvent:e})},_fireMouseEvent:function(e){this.fire(e.type,{originalEvent:e}),"contextmenu"===e.type&&this.hasEventListeners(e.type)&&t.DomEvent.preventDefault(e),"mousedown"!==e.type?t.DomEvent.stopPropagation(e):t.DomEvent.preventDefault(e)}});return t.BaseMarkerMethods={showLabel:function(){return this.label&&this._map&&(this.label.setLatLng(this._latlng),this._map.showLabel(this.label)),this},hideLabel:function(){return this.label&&this.label.close(),this},setLabelNoHide:function(t){this._labelNoHide!==t&&(this._labelNoHide=t,t?(this._removeLabelRevealHandlers(),this.showLabel()):(this._addLabelRevealHandlers(),this.hideLabel()))},bindLabel:function(i,n){var o=this.options.icon?this.options.icon.options.labelAnchor:this.options.labelAnchor,s=t.point(o)||t.point(0,0);return s=s.add(e.prototype.options.offset),n&&n.offset&&(s=s.add(n.offset)),n=t.Util.extend({offset:s},n),this._labelNoHide=n.noHide,this.label||(this._labelNoHide||this._addLabelRevealHandlers(),this.on("remove",this.hideLabel,this).on("move",this._moveLabel,this).on("add",this._onMarkerAdd,this),this._hasLabelHandlers=!0),this.label=new e(n,this).setContent(i),this},unbindLabel:function(){return this.label&&(this.hideLabel(),this.label=null,this._hasLabelHandlers&&(this._labelNoHide||this._removeLabelRevealHandlers(),this.off("remove",this.hideLabel,this).off("move",this._moveLabel,this).off("add",this._onMarkerAdd,this)),this._hasLabelHandlers=!1),this},updateLabelContent:function(t){this.label&&this.label.setContent(t)},getLabel:function(){return this.label},_onMarkerAdd:function(){this._labelNoHide&&this.showLabel()},_addLabelRevealHandlers:function(){this.on("mouseover",this.showLabel,this).on("mouseout",this.hideLabel,this),t.Browser.touch&&this.on("click",this.showLabel,this)},_removeLabelRevealHandlers:function(){this.off("mouseover",this.showLabel,this).off("mouseout",this.hideLabel,this),t.Browser.touch&&this.off("click",this.showLabel,this)},_moveLabel:function(t){this.label.setLatLng(t.latlng)}},t.Icon.Default.mergeOptions({labelAnchor:new t.Point(9,-20)}),t.Marker.mergeOptions({icon:new t.Icon.Default}),t.Marker.include(t.BaseMarkerMethods),t.Marker.include({_originalUpdateZIndex:t.Marker.prototype._updateZIndex,_updateZIndex:function(t){var e=this._zIndex+t;this._originalUpdateZIndex(t),this.label&&this.label.updateZIndex(e)},_originalSetOpacity:t.Marker.prototype.setOpacity,setOpacity:function(t,e){this.options.labelHasSemiTransparency=e,this._originalSetOpacity(t)},_originalUpdateOpacity:t.Marker.prototype._updateOpacity,_updateOpacity:function(){var t=0===this.options.opacity?0:1;this._originalUpdateOpacity(),this.label&&this.label.setOpacity(this.options.labelHasSemiTransparency?this.options.opacity:t)},_originalSetLatLng:t.Marker.prototype.setLatLng,setLatLng:function(t){return this.label&&!this._labelNoHide&&this.hideLabel(),this._originalSetLatLng(t)}}),t.CircleMarker.mergeOptions({labelAnchor:new t.Point(0,0)}),t.CircleMarker.include(t.BaseMarkerMethods),t.Path.include({bindLabel:function(i,n){return this.label&&this.label.options===n||(this.label=new e(n,this)),this.label.setContent(i),this._showLabelAdded||(this.on("mouseover",this._showLabel,this).on("mousemove",this._moveLabel,this).on("mouseout remove",this._hideLabel,this),t.Browser.touch&&this.on("click",this._showLabel,this),this._showLabelAdded=!0),this},unbindLabel:function(){return this.label&&(this._hideLabel(),this.label=null,this._showLabelAdded=!1,this.off("mouseover",this._showLabel,this).off("mousemove",this._moveLabel,this).off("mouseout remove",this._hideLabel,this)),this},updateLabelContent:function(t){this.label&&this.label.setContent(t)},_showLabel:function(t){this.label.setLatLng(t.latlng),this._map.showLabel(this.label)},_moveLabel:function(t){this.label.setLatLng(t.latlng)},_hideLabel:function(){this.label.close()}}),t.Map.include({showLabel:function(t){return this.addLayer(t)}}),t.FeatureGroup.include({clearLayers:function(){return this.unbindLabel(),this.eachLayer(this.removeLayer,this),this},bindLabel:function(t,e){return this.invoke("bindLabel",t,e)},unbindLabel:function(){return this.invoke("unbindLabel")},updateLabelContent:function(t){this.invoke("updateLabelContent",t)}}),e},window);
    </script>

    <script>

 var itm = [{"TrackingAvgSpeed":-1.0,"OverspeedPercent":0,"AvgAllowedSpeed":50.0,"DistanceInMeters":43,"Points":0.0,"Polyline":"qobxHcdujCADC???ICKK??COEMGI??EEGAE?","CalculatedAvgSpeed":21.6},{"TrackingAvgSpeed":-1.0,"OverspeedPercent":0,"AvgAllowedSpeed":50.0,"DistanceInMeters":35,"Points":0.0,"Polyline":"sqbxH}eujCG???GDGFEJ??CJAJ?J@J","CalculatedAvgSpeed":21.6},{"TrackingAvgSpeed":-1.0,"OverspeedPercent":0,"AvgAllowedSpeed":50.0,"DistanceInMeters":257,"Points":0.0,"Polyline":"urbxHscujC@LDHDH??@L?^??A`@GlBKdCKzCIvAInAI|@","CalculatedAvgSpeed":31.68},{"TrackingAvgSpeed":-1.0,"OverspeedPercent":100,"AvgAllowedSpeed":50.0,"DistanceInMeters":300,"Points":0.0,"Polyline":"etbxHkltjCGt@Kx@Ix@O~@Kp@Kr@Qv@]hBaAfF??M\\??G@GBGDEH","CalculatedAvgSpeed":65.73333},{"TrackingAvgSpeed":-1.0,"OverspeedPercent":0,"AvgAllowedSpeed":50.0,"DistanceInMeters":42,"Points":0.0,"Polyline":"i{bxH}ssjCCHCHAJ???NBN??BL??Cj@","CalculatedAvgSpeed":29.4},{"TrackingAvgSpeed":-1.0,"OverspeedPercent":0,"AvgAllowedSpeed":50.0,"DistanceInMeters":105,"Points":0.0,"Polyline":"o{bxHcpsjCqApG","CalculatedAvgSpeed":43.2},{"TrackingAvgSpeed":-1.0,"OverspeedPercent":100,"AvgAllowedSpeed":50.0,"DistanceInMeters":656,"Points":0.0,"Polyline":"a~bxHqgsjCUpA??Ot@Sv@Uz@Wv@??KZ??IV??i@bBW~@Ol@Mp@??G\\Gr@Ej@Cv@?r@??GdCCp@El@Gh@Eh@??Kl@Id@Kf@??Kb@Mb@K^MZO^Q^Wd@??S\\UXWXUT]\\","CalculatedAvgSpeed":68.21053},{"TrackingAvgSpeed":-1.0,"OverspeedPercent":100,"AvgAllowedSpeed":70.0,"DistanceInMeters":716,"Points":0.0,"Polyline":"_ocxHusqjCi@b@cG|EsHbGs@l@a@`@YZSXU\\U^Sb@Sd@Q`@M`@Md@Oh@Kf@??ET??Od@Ox@QdAGl@C\\AZ","CalculatedAvgSpeed":79.8},{"TrackingAvgSpeed":-1.0,"OverspeedPercent":100,"AvgAllowedSpeed":70.0,"DistanceInMeters":21,"Points":0.0,"Polyline":"imdxHalpjCAT?h@","CalculatedAvgSpeed":72.0},{"TrackingAvgSpeed":-1.0,"OverspeedPercent":62,"AvgAllowedSpeed":92.16,"DistanceInMeters":2465,"Points":0.0,"Polyline":"kmdxHajpjC?`A??@nAHrCTpH??HtG??f@db@^rZ??FbGNvL@x@Dx@Br@Dn@??Dn@JbAJfATjBrBnQ??`Flc@??bBxN??RfB??`BjN","CalculatedAvgSpeed":93.24},{"TrackingAvgSpeed":-1.0,"OverspeedPercent":100,"AvgAllowedSpeed":72.76,"DistanceInMeters":2533,"Points":0.0,"Polyline":"iucxHqpijC@F??vCbWfBbORdBZ`C??xAlK\\rCVzBn@jG~ArO??h@fF??h@dFfAjJ??tApL??`Ex]??h@vE??jBjP??D^??|@rH??vB`R","CalculatedAvgSpeed":100.28},{"TrackingAvgSpeed":-1.0,"OverspeedPercent":100,"AvgAllowedSpeed":90.0,"DistanceInMeters":1133,"Points":0.0,"Polyline":"qjbxH{vbjC\\xC??RfB??p@|F??fAnJ??X|B??b@vD??l@dF??f@lE??pArKVxB??H|@Jv@Bd@B^Bb@FdBDtA??FbCBr@???Z?\\A`@Af@Er@K|A??UrC","CalculatedAvgSpeed":98.42553},{"TrackingAvgSpeed":-1.0,"OverspeedPercent":0,"AvgAllowedSpeed":93.94,"DistanceInMeters":1036,"Points":0.0,"Polyline":"w|axHus_jCSdC??_AxJ??YvC??YnC??cAfKCV??qAxM??QdB??ShB??a@dE??WbC??EV??U|B??YjC??C`@??K~@??MdA??c@fE","CalculatedAvgSpeed":84.43636},{"TrackingAvgSpeed":-1.0,"OverspeedPercent":0,"AvgAllowedSpeed":90.0,"DistanceInMeters":2011,"Points":0.0,"Polyline":"qlbxHgy|iC[zC??Gl@??c@hE??[xC??Gj@??AL??MpA??Gj@??Iv@??CR??OrA??CZ??O|A??e@hE??W`C??CV??OvAC\\E`@AT??A\\C^Ad@UjJ??UzI??Cl@??_@bOAd@Cp@Cp@C\\C`@Cb@CTEZ??CR??[pB_@bC??w@|E??aAjG??g@vC??e@lC??a@|B??Kj@??EX??i@zC??GZ??a@`C??_AhF??[bB??SfA??u@hE??s@dE","CalculatedAvgSpeed":80.48},{"TrackingAvgSpeed":-1.0,"OverspeedPercent":82,"AvgAllowedSpeed":57.02,"DistanceInMeters":245,"Points":0.0,"Polyline":"glcxHyjwiCG\\Mr@Gf@??Gv@Cf@Af@Ab@@f@?b@@f@Bb@??Dj@??D`@D\\F`@Jd@Jd@Ld@","CalculatedAvgSpeed":56.475},{"TrackingAvgSpeed":-1.0,"OverspeedPercent":86,"AvgAllowedSpeed":52.73,"DistanceInMeters":1282,"Points":0.0,"Polyline":"mkcxH{tviCNf@N^NZLV??LR??JR??bA`B^r@??|@zA??f@`A??LR??HP??f@~@??P`@Tf@??NXN\\??Vn@??DL??Xr@Rb@??t@pB??Rf@??r@fB??Rh@??Pb@??LX??p@dB??HR??@D??JV??HP??`@fA??LX??j@zA??LX??n@bB??`AdC??Pd@??N^??FN??Vn@??FP??`@`A??|@|B??~@`C??Xt@??^bA??Zt@??h@vA??^~@??Nb@??h@rA??~@bC","CalculatedAvgSpeed":53.16},{"TrackingAvgSpeed":-1.0,"OverspeedPercent":41,"AvgAllowedSpeed":83.09,"DistanceInMeters":1446,"Points":0.0,"Polyline":"q|axHqzsiCTh@??Rh@??JZ??`@bA??FN??Tj@??t@jB??j@vA??rHfRPb@L^L`@J\\J^Pr@b@fB??z@dD??r@rC??nB`I??lA~E??fCbK??XjA??p@jCXdAz@xC??p@xB??fAnD??\\hA??Rr@PE","CalculatedAvgSpeed":83.82857}];
 var polylines = [], points = [], behavePolylines = [];
 $(function(){
    var map;
      function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
          zoom: 8
        });
      }
      function getRandomColor() {
                var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
                var color = '#';
                for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
                    color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
                }
                return color;
            };
            function getColor(calculated, allowed){
                var diff = calculated - allowed;
                if(diff <=0){
                    return "#0ea00f";
                } else if(diff >0 && diff <= 15){
                    return "#ff6a00"
                } else if(diff > 15){
                    return "#ff0000"
                } else return "#000"
            }
            function renderTrip (trip) {
                //if (!data.success) return;
                // var trip = JSON.parse(data.trip);
                $.each(polylines, function (e, val) {
                    map.removeLayer(val);
                });

                var tripPolyPoints = L.PolylineUtil.decode(data.POLY);
                var tripPoly = L.polyline(tripPolyPoints,
                {
                   color: "#000000",
                   opacity: 0.6,
                   weight: 4
                });

                tripPoly.addTo(map);
                map.fitBounds(tripPoly.getBounds());
                polylines.push(tripPoly);

                for (var i = 0; i < trip.length; i++) {

                    var calculated = (trip[i].CalculatedAvgSpeed).toFixed(1);
                    var allowed = (trip[i].AvgAllowedSpeed).toFixed(1);
                    var distance = (trip[i].DistanceInMeters / 1000.0).toFixed(2);
                    var polylinePoints = L.PolylineUtil.decode(trip[i].Polyline);
                    var polyline = L.polyline(polylinePoints, {
                        color: getColor(calculated, allowed),
                        opacity: 1,
                        weight: 8
                    }).bindLabel('Średnia prędkość: ' + calculated + ' KM/H<br>Średnia dopuszczalna prędkość: ' 
                    + allowed + ' KM/H<br>Długość odcinka: ' + distance + ' KM');
                    polyline.addTo(map);
                    polylines.push(polyline);

                }
                var origPolyPoints = L.PolylineUtil.decode(data.bfPoly);
                var origPoly = L.polyline(origPolyPoints,
                {
                   color: "#0000ff",
                   opacity: 0.5,
                   weight: 5
                });

                origPoly.addTo(map);
                polylines.push(origPoly);
            }
            renderTrip(itm);

});

    </script>
      <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_KAY&callback=initMap"
    async defer></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

**Error Message :**

> Uncaught (in promise) yd {message: "initMap is not a function", name:
>   "InvalidValueError", stack: "Error↵    at new yd  message: "initMap is
>   not a function" name: "InvalidValueError"

Answer (score 0):

Your `initMap` function needs to be placed in global scope so that the Map API's callback can find and call this function.

```
  <script>
    var itm = [];
    var polylines = [],
      points = [],
      behavePolylines = [];

    var map;

    function initMap() {
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: { lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 },
        zoom: 8
      });
    }

    $(function() {

      function getRandomColor() {
        var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
        var color = '#';
        for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
          color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
        }
        return color;
      };
      ...
    });
 </script>
```

Please check out related thread [Google Maps Javascript API not loading reliably](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58028602/google-maps-javascript-api-not-loading-reliably/58051149)

Hope this helps!